# mount by major / minor without dev node

Tags: c, linux

In linux is there a way to mount a block device from its major and minor number by using only system calls(user space), but without temporarily creating a dev node file.

I already had a look at sys/mount.h(https://linux.die.net/man/2/mount)! (i 
try to implement this in c)

Comment: You're calling this from *within* the kernel?

Comment: no from user space

Comment: No, you'll need to create a device node to perform the mounting in this case; however it's a single system call (`mknod`) to create the device node, and it can be absolutely *anywhere* (even in `/tmp`)

Comment: this is what i know, but i was curious if there is any way to bypass it like an ioctl, feels like a detour to create a node first